# Horizontally and Vertically Center Paragraph text Simultaneously

Tags: html, css

I need to horizontally *and* vertically center text in a paragraph. The paragraph itself *must* fill 100% of the available `height` and `width` of the parent element without setting an explicit/static `width` for the paragraph (percentage like `100%` is acceptable).

**HTML**

```
<div>
<p>Sudo make me a sandwich.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div
{
 background-image: url('idahoisntafraidofgorillas.png');
 height: 138px;
 width: 100%;
}

p
{
 display: table-cell;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: center;
}
```

Ideally this should not require anything greater than CSS level 2. The current code doesn't actually center the text unless I set a static `width` however that would spam up the CSS I'm working on so I'm seeking a more elegant and proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `vertical-align: middle` also add `display: table` to `div`

```css
div {
 height: 138px;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: table;
}

p {
 display: table-cell;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Sudo make me a sandwich.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked! Ha not sure why I didn't think of that. Have to wait ten minutes to accept so will up-vote for now. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Its a good hack but using `display: table-cell;` has some serious performance drawbacks if you use it a large number of elements.

Comment: @max really? source?

Comment: @Aziz. I do remember the source to be pretty creditable but can't for life of me remember the exact source. Tried to find it now but I'm only finding comparisons to flexbox.

Comment: @max Add `-flex` to your search queries to make search engines behave. :-)

Comment: I cant find the original source but closest I can get is: "That said, if you can get away with it, regular block layout (non-float), will usually be as fast or faster than new flexbox since it’s always single-pass. But new flexbox should be faster than using tables or writing custom JS-base layout code." - Ojan Vafai, who wrote much of the implementation in WebKit & Blink https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/10/Flexbox-layout-isn-t-slow?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

Set the `line-height`, `vertical-align:middle;`, and make sure there is no extra margin, `margin:0px;` all on the paragraph element.

```css
div {
 height: 138px;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

p {
  margin:0px;
  line-height:138px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Sudo make me a sandwich.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I use `* {border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;}` by default; some people get excited, bent over and go through some crazy convoluted approaches though it's a waste of time to complicate stuff.